# Как задать tab-у длину

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго дня!
На форме лежит richtextbox с acceptstab=true. По умолчанию символ tab \t в нем идентичен 8-ми пробелам. Можно ли как-то встроенными средствами изменить это значение на 4?

Comment: Идентичен? Если вы нажмёте Tab, то чтобы его потом удалить надо 8 раз нажать backspace?

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154204/5045688)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, оно

Comment: @АндрейNOP я имел в виду длину. Думаю, вы меня поняли